# iPhone:Storyboard issue with default labels

Tags: iphone

I created views using Storyboard. In one of the view controller, i added a TableView as its the easy way of doing in storyboard. I am seeing two labels in each cell by default. I want to customize it now, i don't want these two labels here and i want to add some image view, textfield etc. The problem now is, i am not able to remove this default two labels from cell. Can someone guide me? Also, please share me the Apple official link where i can learn about Storyboard and complete usage.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the cell and select "Custom" for "Style" in the right sidebar menu (under the attributes inspector).